# Detect type of Sandbox (Salesforce)

Tags: salesforce, simple-salesforce

Salesforce supports different sandboxes.

For example "partial" or "development" sandbox.

Is there a way to detect which kind of sandbox my script is connected to?

I use Python and simple_salesforce.

Comment: Hey, why did you bounty the question, I thought all was good? It ended up with me anyway instead of attracting better answers. Thanks I guess ;) Anything else needed here?

Comment: @eyescream the bounty was for "reward existing answer". Yes, everything is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Python's not good enough. I can give hints but you'll have to experiment a bit yourself.

https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce "Additional features" says there's internal class that can expose to you session_id and instance.

You can use these to craft a HTTP GET call to

```
Authorization: Bearer {session_id}
{instance}/services/data/v51.0/limits
```

The ["limits"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm) resource will tell you (among others) what's the data and file storage available in this org. It'll return a JSON similar to

```
{
    ...
    "DataStorageMB" : {
        "Max" : 200,
        "Remaining" : 196
    },
    ...
}
```

Use `DataStorageMB.Max` and table at bottom of https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_environments.htm&type=5 to figure out where you are. 200 => Developer, 1024 => Developer Pro...

---

Edit - if you'd be using Apex (maybe exposed as REST service, "simple salesforce" has nice built-in to access them)

```
Integer storageLimit = OrgLimits.getMap().get('DataStorageMB').getLimit();
System.debug(storageLimit);
String sandboxType;
switch on storageLimit{
    when 200 {
        sandboxType = 'Developer';
    }
    when 1024 {
        sandboxType = 'Developer Pro';
    }
    when 5120 {
        sandboxType = 'Partial Copy';
    }
    when else {
        sandboxType = 'Full Copy';
    }
}
System.debug(sandboxType);
```

Comment: I get: `SalesforceRefusedRequest: Request refused for https://foo.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/limits/. Response content: [{'message': 'limits resource is not enabled', 'errorCode': 'API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG'}]`

Comment: Does connecting user's Profile have checkboxes ticked: "API Enabled", "View Setup and Configuration", "Manage Users"?

Comment: I use a different account now, which has more permissions. Now it works. Thank you very much. Although it is quite dirty to detect the sandbox type this way. Does Salesforce have a feedback channel where you can create feature requests?

Comment: Post an idea or upvote existing one like https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TtbOQAS - anybody can post. You need valid sf "production-like" login (free developer edition or trailblazer account works too, you don't need to be paid customer/registered partner). And if you have production access - there should be Help&Training link, depending on support level ($) you should be able to raise a case with them or "just" post in SF community, pick other customers' brains.

Comment: In Apex (server-side language) you can get this "200" as 1-liner [`System.debug(OrgLimits.getMap().get('DataStorageMB').getLimit());`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_OrgLimits.htm). You could make a REST service returning the sandbox type but it's still bit stupid, another API call. You could discuss with your admin making a "custom setting" to hold the info and writing the value to it whenever sandbox is created (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Steps to find the sandbox type:
Setup --> Deployment Settings --> continue -- > you will find the type of sandbox.